# What's the difference between the phrases "to train with" and "to do training with"?

Tags: difference, sentence-usage

[Source](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ultimate%20spider%20man%20episode%201&oq=ult&aqs=chrome.5.69i59l2j69i57j69i60l2j35i39.3991j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> Spider-Man is approached to train with S.H.I.E.L.D.

I was wondering (whether/ if) will it make any difference if I phrase the sentence as follows:

> Spider-Man is approached to do training with S.H.I.E.L.D.

Is there grammatical, meaning or usage difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

To me, being approached "to train with S.H.I.E.L.D." suggests that he has been asked to take a training course.  It probably means that he'll be attending training sessions on a number of separate occasions.

Being approached "to do training with S.H.I.E.L.D." could mean the same, or it could refer to a one-off training session.  It is also possible that he could be one of the teachers or trainers, although it is still more likely that he is a student or trainee.